# display.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-KFcbfWUi'

Tags: linux, r, bash, shell, csv

I'm using [Rio](https://github.com/jeroenjanssens/data-science-at-the-command-line/blob/master/tools/Rio) and I have a `sample.csv` which looks as following

```
hour,count
0300,0
0300,0
0300,1
0300,1
0300,2
0301,1
0301,2
0301,2
0301,3
```

I run following command:

`$ < sample.csv Rio -ge 'g + geom_bar(df, aes(hour, count))' | display`

and I get

```
display.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-Gvr3kRZh' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
```

from what I know geom_bar expects the dataset first which is `df` and then columns, i'm not sure why i don't see the graph, anyone knows what am i missing?

thanks

Comment: See http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html. It expects the mapping first, then the data. And you don't actually have to specify `df` for the data, because it's already been captured in `g`.

Comment: And I think you need to specify `stat='identity'` if you want to specify a `y` aesthetic.

Comment: @bgoldst thanks that was it i wish to accept it if would be submitted via answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html). It expects the mapping first, then the data. And you don't actually have to specify `df` for the data, because it's already been captured in `g`.

And I think you need to specify `stat='identity'` if you want to specify a `y` aesthetic.